# Image is changing size on hover

Tags: html, less

I have little problem with my theme. When I hover on images it looks like middle images are decreasing abous one pixel.

Here's the link  [site](http://new.pfkusu.linuxpl.info/albums/)

And code

```
#grid{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    &.col-3 .single{
        width: 33.333333333333333333333333333333%;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
    a{
        display: inherit;
    }
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        transition: all .5s ease;
    }
    &:hover img{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    &:hover img:hover{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Is this pure CSS or LESS or something?

Answer (score 0):

modify your CSS its solved :D

---

files to edit: setting.css.lens[line no.524]

---

files to edit: setting.css.lens[line no.515]

---

---

> CSS

```
#grid:hover img:hover {
opacity: 1;
overflow: hidden;
zoom: 1;
}

#grid img {
overflow: hidden;
height: auto;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for help, but your solution isn't working. Instead I change width from 33.333333333333333333333333333333% to 33.3%. The difference is minimal and this annoying one pixel border isn't appearing. :)